# Ember include in-app shared components addon in in-app engine

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In an Ember application that contains an in-app engine (my-engine) and an in-app addon for shared components (shared-components), how do you include the shared components addon as a dependency of the in-app engine so you may use the components in the templates of the engine? The shared components addon has two components, global-header and global-footer.

Comment: Have you tried to just use it? Its transpiled to AMD, and so `import foo from 'my-addon/foo` should work.

Comment: I don't think I explained correctly, I'm looking to add the shared component addon in an engine template. For example, I'm trying to use {{global-header}} in a template of the engine and nothing is rendered.

Comment: So you want to use the code across apps versus treating each engine as an independent routable application?

Comment: Creating dependencies within ember engines is something that is currently still being worked out unless you're using the `ember-engines` addon.

https://youtu.be/aYIhgDRLUa0?t=1370
https://github.com/dgeb/ember-engines

I would think that you could import the addon's component into the parent's namespace, and then declare it as a dependency for your engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dependency (in-app addon) you want to use from host app, and you want to use it within your engine (in-app engine), you should include it directly in your engine, and then have your engine share it with the application.

Currently, I believe you've described:

```
  [ application ]
    + engine
    + addon
      + component
```

And you want to use the component within your engine.

Instead, what I would suggest is if your engine needs it, give it your engine.

```
[ application ]
  + engine
      + addon
        + component
```

If your application also needs it you could have it be a dependency of your application as well *or* share the dependency from your engine with your application.

Sharing dependencies from an engine with an application is described at the new [ember-engine website](http://ember-engines.com/guide/sharing-components-and-more).